# XAML C# Function across multiple windows

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I've got a program I am working on that has multiple windows. The windows are similar in functionality and I want to have a single event handler to cover a button press event for each window in the application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to bind a handler in code behind you can encapsulate a handler by delegate and inject into the Windows which are required it.

For instance using `Action<T>`:

```
Action<string> commonHandler = (parameter) => 
   { 
         // handler code here 
   };


class MyWindiow
{

   public MyWindiow(Action<string> handler)
   { 
         // store to local and assign to button click
         // button.CLick += (o, e) => { handler(parameterToBepassed); }
   }
}
```

Comment: In which file in the project should the action code be placed?

Comment: @Will : it depends on your projects structure and whther some windows are created manually

Comment: The windows were all created at design time. I was hoping for a solution that would allow me to place a function in some place, like the app.xaml.cs file, which I'm not even certain what that is or what it does, and call it in the window as necessary. I think this is close to what I want, but I'm still not sure as to how to implement it.

Comment: @Will: if method is static you can reference it using "{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}"

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using a framework to help you out here. My favorite is [Prism v4](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

If you follow the [M-V-VM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) design pattern you're life will be a lot easier. You'll need to understand [Data Binding and DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

---

That being said, if you decide to go this path, you can bind each of your windows to a command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoFooCommand}" Content="DoFoo"/>
```

You're ViewModel would have a [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommand(v=PandP.40).aspx) member to execute.

```
public class SomeViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        DoFooCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteFoo);
    }

    public DelegateCommand DoFooCommand { get; set; }

    private void ExecuteFoo()
    {
        //Use the EventAggregator to publish a common event
    }
}
```

And finally, somewhere else in your solution you'll have a code file/class that subscribes to the event and waits for someone to publish the event to process it.

```
public class SomeOtherPlace
{
    public SomeOtherPlace()
    {
        //Use the EventAggregator to subscribe to the common event
    }

    public void FooBarMethodToCallWhenEventIsPublished(SomePayload payload)
    {
        //Do whatever you need to do here...
    }
}
```

I realize some of the things were left out (such as what a "SomePayload" is... look into the EventAggregator information), but I did not want to get into it too much. Just give you a guide on where to go for information and some base code to work off of. If you decide to use the EventAggregator then you'll need to ensure that your subscribing call and publishing calls are utilizing the SAME instance of the EventAggregator. You can do this by looking into [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). Prism is setup to work with MEF perfectly... I'm not going to lie. Doing all this requires a bit of a learning curve, but it will be worthwhile in the end when you can unit test your ViewModels easily and have your code loosely coupled. The EventAggregator is a great way for different classes to communicate to each other without relying on knowing about each other. And MEF is great for having a Container for your services that you want to utilize across your application.

Hope that gave you a bit of insight on how to go about doing what you want to do on the correct path.